# Rails and Ajax substitute content of div error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Have a problem, im try substitute my div #adm_content whit one partial, how i make whit my comments but the ajax dont response, im using the remote true to substitute,see the link:

```
   <li><%= link_to "Editar perfil", edit_user_path(current_user), :remote => true %>
```

im creathe the  edit.js.erb, are this:

```
$("#adm_content").html("<%= j render :partial =>'users/edit' %>");
```

and im my user_controller i put the respond in js see :

```
respond_to :js

  def edit
    @user = current_user
    respond_with @user
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      respond_with @user
    else
      redirect_to "edit",:notice=>"Falha ao atualizar informações !"
    end
  end
```

please, when i click in the link the div dont change, what is wrong please

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors in the browser JS console?

Comment: Try `render 'users/edit'` instead and also check the console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I use JQuery to handle Ajax request in rails. If you have JQuery in rails app you can do this.

view:

```
<li><%= link_to "Editar perfil", edit_user_path(current_user), :id => "edit_profile" %>


 <script>
   $(function(){
     $("#edit_profile").click(function(){
       url = $(this).href
       $.get(url, function(data, status){
          alert(data)
       })
     })
   })
 </script>
```

controller:

```
 def edit
   @user = current_user
   respond_with @user # or use render "edit"
 end
```

Comment: I get this error: Routing Error

uninitialized constant UserController
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

Comment: no redirect, the action update is   def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      respond_with @user
    else
      redirect_to "edit",:notice=>"Falha ao atualizar informações !"
    end
  end